# HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 400 Bad Request on using wget for downloading dropbox files in CentOS

Tags: centos, wget, http, download, dropbox

The file is around 447MB. I cannot download it using the following command in CentOS. How can I download https://www.dropbox.com/sh/6yd1ygtyc3yd981/AABVeEqzC08YQv4UZk7lNHvya?dl=0&preview=CIFAR-FS.tar.gz using commandline in CentOS?

```
[jalal@goku multimodal]$  wget --max-redirect=20 -O download.zip https://www.dropbox.com/sh/6yd1ygtyc3yd981/AABVeEqzC08YQv4UZk7lNHvya?dl=0&preview=CIFAR-FS.tar.gz
[1] 20919
[jalal@goku multimodal]$ --2020-09-30 21:27:03--  https://www.dropbox.com/sh/6yd1ygtyc3yd981/AABVeEqzC08YQv4UZk7lNHvya?dl=0
Resolving www.dropbox.com (www.dropbox.com)... 162.125.4.1, 2620:100:6019:1::a27d:401
Connecting to www.dropbox.com (www.dropbox.com)|162.125.4.1|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Location: /sh/raw/6yd1ygtyc3yd981/AABVeEqzC08YQv4UZk7lNHvya [following]
--2020-09-30 21:27:03--  https://www.dropbox.com/sh/raw/6yd1ygtyc3yd981/AABVeEqzC08YQv4UZk7lNHvya
Reusing existing connection to www.dropbox.com:443.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 400 Bad Request
2020-09-30 21:27:05 ERROR 400: Bad Request.

^C
[1]+  Exit 8                  wget --max-redirect=20 -O download.zip https://www.dropbox.com/sh/6yd1ygtyc3yd981/AABVeEqzC08YQv4UZk7lNHvya?dl=0
[jalal@goku multimodal]$ ls
total 16
16 drwxrwxrwt. 107 root  root    12288 Sep 30 21:00 ..
 0 -rw-r--r--.   1 jalal cs-grad     0 Sep 30 21:27 download.zip
 0 drwxr-xr-x.   2 jalal cs-grad    26 Sep 30 21:27 .
[jalal@goku multimodal]$ rm download.zip


[jalal@goku ~]$ lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    :core-4.1-amd64:core-4.1-noarch
Distributor ID: CentOS
Description:    CentOS Linux release 7.8.2003 (Core)
Release:    7.8.2003
Codename:   Core
```

Comment: have you tried the URL without the parameters? ... only the https://www.dropbox.com/sh/6yd1ygtyc3yd981/AABVeEqzC08YQv4UZk7lNHvya

Comment: Have a look at this: https://superuser.com/questions/470664/how-to-download-dropbox-files-using-wget-command